# Arduino to python serial read split

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, pyserial

Hi I am staring out and have cracked sending multiple bits of information from Python to my Arduino. I now would like to send information from my Arduino to python I have looked at may examples but they all send to show only one line of information being sent.

his is what i am stuck with.The Arduino is sending a start number  255 then an ID then the information it looks like this on the terminal window.

```
255  start chr

1    ch ID

99   Value
```

I want to split these back into there individual arrays in python.

thanks for any tips.

Comment: Is the arduino actually outputting `"    start chr"`? Are there two newlines between values? Or do you receive `255199`?

Comment: it just outputs   255  1 99 on separate lines.  i would like to get them into data0 data1 data2.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a dedicated separator character (e.g. a comma) and split the strings accordingly. That is: write the Arduino side of your code in such a way that parsing on the Python side becomes easy.

Comment: don't know what you mean but my arduino  Serial.print(data0) Serial.print(data1) Serial.print(data2)

Comment: @jamesjordan: `print` or `println`? That code would produce `255199`, which is impossible to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Print the Arduino items into a line with a delimiter such as a comma like so:

```
  Serial.print(VALUE 1);
  Serial.print((" , "));
  Serial.print(VALUE 2);
  Serial.print((" , "));    
  Serial.println(LAST VALUE);
```

Using println for the last value will combine all previous print into one line. With Arduino Serial Monitor results something like this:

```
VALUE 1 , VALUE 2 , LAST VALUE
```

You can easily split the values in python and assign a variable to each value like taking values from an array:

```
SERIALDATA= sensorData.readline() #Read line of text from Arduino
DATASPLIT= SERIALDATA.split(' , ') #Splits the line of text into array of strings composed of each individual sensor data

pyVALUE1= DATASPLIT [0]
pyVALUE2= DATASPLIT [1]
pyFINALVAL= DATASPLIT [2]
```